# Does Intel SGX provide software memory protection in simulation mode?

Tags: intel, sgx

I have some 4th generation Intel CPU and I want to run some Intel SGX application. I use release simulation mode.

[Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/709072) you can see that SGX simulation doesn't provide HARDWARE protection! However, I would like to know if Intel SGX provides some kind of SOFTWARE protection in release simulation mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the goal of simulation mode is to develop enclave on non-supporting platforms and to enable debug of enclaves.
In simulation mode, the enclave is running as a standard process in regular memory and can be debugged and accessed like any other process in the system.